# Should I be freeing up any of these powershell objects or snap-ins after I'm done with them?

Tags: powershell

We believe that a powershell script we have might be causing a memory leak.  I have pasted the relevant object-creation statements below, I wonder if I should be freeing up any of these objects at the end of the script?

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
..
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
..
$xSessionResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $xSessionURI -Headers $headers -Method POST -Body $sessionBody -ContentType $contentType
..
$VMList = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $VMListURL -TimeoutSec 500 -ContentType "application/JSON"
..
Send-MailMessage @param
```

Grateful for any advice - sorry - as I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Why do you think your script might be causing a memory leak?

Comment: I don't see anything on the surface that would cause a memory leak or any other kind of issue outside of the current PowerShell session.

Comment: Looks ok, try pausing between each line until you find which line is doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your Powershell script is literally endless, you should not worry about memory leaks, as all memory gets released once the parent `powershell.exe` process ends. If it creates any COM objects, these should be released properly, though, as they create more processes that serve them, such as creating an `Outlook.Application` COM object starts `outlook.exe` process which does need to be gracefully ended with COM-based methods, or in extreme cases, `Stop-Process`. If, however, it's a nonpaged (or paged) pool that gets leaked, then you should check if you leave any instances open or wrongly terminated that leave trails in either pool. But, if your script isn't run with admin or system privileges, you should never get kernel pool memory leak with your own actions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your assistance.  I thought that was the case but wanted to check with those better informed!